# react-native renderRow with button: push rowData to button-function

Tags: javascript, react-native

- [ 24.1 ] What's the **version** of React Native you're using?
- [ both ] Does this occur on iOS, Android or both?
- [ Mac ] Are you using Mac, Linux or Windows?

I'm doing this:

```
_onPress(data) {
    Actions.shopProducts(data);
}
```

...

```
renderRow(rowData){
return (
<Button onPress={this._onPress.bind(this)}>
    <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <Image
                source={{uri: rowData.image}}
            />

            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.smallText}>Name: {rowData.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.smallText}>Straße: {rowData.address}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.smallText}>Ort: {rowData.location}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
    </Button>
);
}
```

...

I'm getting following error:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): undefined is not an
>   object (evaluating 'this._onPress.bind') renderRow @...

I'm actually using react-native-router-flux and react-native-button.

What causes this error? I can't understand this...

Best regards

Edit:
Now I want to know how to push the rowData to my Button-function... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to 'bind' the `renderRow` itself , like:

```
<ListView 
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
  renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} 
  ... 
/>
```

And for passing data to the `_onPress` method, do this:

```
<Button onPress={this._onPress.bind(this, rowData)}>
```

Comment: This is exactly what caused the error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know, how to push the rowData to my function?

Comment: @AlbanVeliu dont forget to pass the `dataSource` attribute, take a look at my updated answer

Comment: I've done this. But I can't push the rowData to my function "_onPress"

Comment: This should not be a problem. Try ```<Button onPress={this._onPress(rowData).bind(this)}>```

Comment: @AlbanVeliu , try : `<Button onPress={this._onPress.bind(this, rowData)}>`

Comment: @Cherniv again: Thank you a lot. This is the answer. Didn't know that I can bind more than one variable.

Comment: @pinewood this is now working. I don't know why. I tested it before and it was not working for me.